# JSF Scope problem

Tags: jsf, scope, jsf-2, communication, javabeans

first of all sorry for my english. I put my question in various german Forums but i didnt get an answer :-( maybe you can help me.

I work with JSF 2.0. We have to create a webapplication that connects to a backend server where all the informations are stored - that is no problem.

My problem is this one:
I have e.g. 2 users.
User 1 logs into the system -> a mesage is sent to backend server -> message will be received with user informations -> user id will be set to 1
User 2 logs into the system -> ... -> user id will be set to 2.
BUT the ID of user 1 will be also set to 1.
That means both users share one instance of my User class?
I thought each user gets his own instance of java classes where only HIS informations are stored.

Here is a bit code:

login.xhtml

```
<h:body>
<f:view>
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}" />
<h:inputSecret id="passwort" value="#{user.password}" />
....
<h:commandButton id="login" action="#{communicator.validate}" />
```

You enter user and passwort the the communicator sends a message to the backend and receives this.

Communicator.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "communicator")
@SessionScoped
public class Communicator implements EventReceiver {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{user}")
    private User user;

    private BackendEvent backendEvent;

validate();
login();

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
```

And now the message from the backend will be received containing all user informations:

```
private void handleLoginTell(LoginTell loginTell) {
    logger.addToLog("handle LoginTell");
    user.setSessionId(loginTell.getSessionId());
    user.setName(loginTell.getLogin());
    user.setLogged(true);
}
```

The user class is just a simple Class with getter/setter methods and three fields: username and password and sessionid.

---

If two user go on my site, i thought for each user a new lifecycle will be created with new instances of my sessionscoped beans.
But.. here my users seem to share just one bean. But why?
Can you maybe explain me where my fault is?

Regards
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

The problem is apparently the scope of the `user` variable - so how is it registered in the context? More importantly, what is its scope? That's where you should look for the cause of the problem.

**Clarification:** I see your problem here:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{user}")
private User user;
```

What is `#{user}`? Where is it defined? There must be a managed bean by that name, or it must be added to the context in some other way. The problem is that it appears to have application scope. Context variables can have all kinds of scopes, not just session scope.